# Collections.sort doesn't work on List<Point2D.Double>

Tags: java, swing, sorting, arraylist, collections

I use `List<Point2D.Double> serie` in my grapher to store point coordinates. When I want to sort, I decided to use `Collections.sort(serie)` but it shows that there is a mistake like

> There can't be double type

So how can I sort `List<Point2D.Double>` by `x` coordinates?

Comment: show us the exception

Comment: "but it shows that there is a mistake" you need to be more specific. Post error what you are getting to (1) let others with similar error find your question and possible answers (2) let people who knows what such error means write answer before need to create code which will reproduce your problem.

Comment: Do you get a compilation error? If it is the case, you need to provide a custom comparator because the `Point2D.Double` class does not implement the `Comparable` interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) of `Collections.sort(List<T>)` you can see

> All elements in the list must implement the Comparable interface

which is enforced by

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

So list should be declared to store elements of type which extends/implements `Comparable` but `Point2D.Double` doesn't implement `Comparable` so it is not valid type.

For this cases Java adds

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

method which allows you to create your own Comparator so you could compare elements which don't implement Comparable, or to compare them in a different way than predefined.

So your code can look like

```
Collections.sort(serie, new Comparator<Point2D.Double>() {
    public int compare(Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2) {
        return Double.compare(p1.getX(), p2.getX());
    }
});
```

or you can write it in Java 8 like

```
Collections.sort(serie, Comparator.comparingDouble(Point2D.Double::getX));
```

or even

```
serie.sort(Comparator.comparingDouble(Point2D.Double::getX));
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works! sometimes it difficult to me to read english API (english is not my native language)

Comment: @Denis Yes, I get what you mean. API tend to be written in a way that to fully understand it requires from us additional test code to make sure if we understand it correctly :)

Answer (score 2):

`Point2D` does not implement the `Comparable` interface.  You will need to create a custom [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) which performs the operation you want and pass it to the `sort` method along with your list, for example...

```
Collections.sort(serie, new Comparator<Point2D.Double>() {
    public int compare(Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2) {
        return (int)(p1.getX() - p2.getX());
    }
});
```

Comment: But is not it Point2D.Double that is Double a class defined as inner class of Point2D. Is it Point2D that needs the comparator/comparable or the Double class inside it?

Comment: @muasif80: `Point2D.Double` is both, a nested class and a subclass of `Point2D`, so it doesn’t matter which class doesn’t implement `Comparable` (both don’t) as *points have no natural order in general*.

Comment: Well, you have an instance of Point2D.Double, so this ensures that only Point2D.Double can be compared. Of you want to compare any instance of Point2D the you can change the requirement of the Comparator to match (<Point2D>)