# Comparator for Java Point2D does not work

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I have an array of 2D points in Java and want to sort it. I have used comparators from different websites, like for example from [Collections.sort doesn't work on List<Point2D.Double>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030348/collections-sort-doesnt-work-on-listpoint2d-double) but none of them work for me.

If I for example use the following code:

```
Point2D[] points = new Point2D[numPoints];
// add some points

Collections.sort(points, new Comparator<Point2D.Double>() {
                public int compare(Point2D.Double p1, Point2D.Double p2) {
                    return (int)(p1.getX() - p2.getX());
                }
            });
```

I always get the following error message:

```
error: no suitable method found for sort(Point2D[],<anonymous Comparator<Double>>)
                        Collections.sort(points, new Comparator<Point2D.Double>() {
                                   ^
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (argument mismatch; Point2D[] cannot be converted to List<T#2>))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)
1 error
```

Is there any obvious reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

You have an array `...[]` hence you need [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html), not `Collections.sort` which is for any Collection like List.

```
Arrays.sort(points,
    Comparator.comparingDouble(Point2D::getX)
              .thenComparingDouble(Point2D::getY));
```

Furthermore [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) has nice methods for (several) comparing fields.

Comment: Shouldn't be `comparingDouble(Point2D::getX)` instead of `comparingDouble(Point2D.Double::getX)`? Or is  not `java.awt.geom.Point2D`?

Comment: Thank you to both of you, both Information are correct and it works now :)

Comment: @DORpapst  Consider using a serious development environment. Intellij, for example, would probably have proposed `Arrays.sort()` as a code completion for `sort(`.  Ctrl-P would have shown that the parameters list of `Collections.sort()` does not include arrays.

Comment: It’s kind of weird, because VScode works quite well but the Java autocorrection is randomly not working